# Bitcoin not confirmed by recipient

Tags: transactions, fraud

I sent bitcoins to the address I was given (double checked). The recipient is claiming they did not receive it. I sent them a payment at 10:46PM EST that was received.  I sent a second payment yesterday at 3:53PM EST.  I am showing it confirmed on my end and on block explorer. Are they lying? Please see below for btc address.

3Hcu6jtGzFc6YoLCufAZxtys1PTe5qZYvZ

Answer (score 0):

**If the recipient claims they have not received money they either don't sufficiently understand Bitcoin or are lying to you.**

---

A blockchain explorer shows for address 3Hcu6jtGzFc6YoLCufAZxtys1PTe5qZYvZ

- Sent Confirmed 0.01120678BTC Jan 21, 2024, 11:17 PMUTC
  Transaction hash: 362527aad4dacfffa4deb57ec7c1f26b5d07591101d92c6303782bb013b40143
- Received Confirmed 0.01120678BTC Jan 21, 2024, 10:10 PMUTC
  Transaction Hash: 3da769d5ccaf10395650ded0560734fe79f0f1bdf99d65f2e58e3cbb8eedda99

This by itself is proof they received that amount of money and spent it an hour later.

In the Bitcoin network, you can't spend money which you haven't received. This is evidence of incompetence or malice on the part of the receiver.

---

The recipient of a Bitcoin transaction plays no part in the receipt of bitcoin. They can receive money even if their wallet is offline or destroyed.

They can subsequently access the money by, if necessary, recreating a destroyed/lost/paper wallet by installing wallet software and using a recovery phrase or opening a backup file or importing a private key.

Wallets don't contain money, they check the blockchain to see how much money has been received at addresses they have control over.

Every wallet either has their own copy of the blockchain or access to a copy.

If the blockchain has a record of the transaction, the recipient has control of the money and no one else does.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are dealing with a scammer. If the block explorer shows that your transaction was confirmed and sent to the correct address, then there is no way that the recipient did not receive it. They are probably trying to trick you into sending more money or giving them your private keys. Do not fall for their lies and do not send them anything else. You should report them to the platform where you found them and warn others about their scam. I hope you can recover your funds somehow.

Answer (score -2):

To verify if your transaction was successful, you can use a blockchain explorer1 to check the status of your Bitcoin transaction and see if it has been confirmed, and how many times it has been confirmed23. You will need to enter your Bitcoin transaction ID (TxID), which you can find in your wallet or exchange, or your Bitcoin address, which is the destination of your payment.

If your transaction has been confirmed at least six times, it means that it is officially recorded and verified on the blockchain, and the recipient should have received it. If your transaction has not been confirmed, it means that it is still waiting in the mempool, and it may take longer depending on the network congestion and the fee you paid.

If the recipient is claiming that they did not receive your payment, even though your transaction has been confirmed, they may be lying or mistaken. You can ask them to provide proof that they did not receive it, such as a screenshot of their wallet balance or a link to their address on a blockchain explorer. You can also contact the platform or service that you used to send the payment, and ask them to investigate the issue.